# IDE для написания Android приложений

Tags: android, ide, c++

Интересует среда разработки для написания графических приложений на С++ для андроида.

Answer (score 1):

Мы делаем так: берем Eclipse (CDT) и ставим ADT Plugin. Устанавливаем Android NDK и добавляем ndk-build в список сборщиков. При полной пересборке сначала собирается C/C++ код, затем Java код. По Java отлаживаемся из Eclipse, а по C/C++ с помощью ndk-gdb. Не то, чтобы очень удобно, но работать можно.

Comment: А зачем это ВООБЩЕ (С++ для разработки под Android)? Java что ли не хватает?

Comment: C/C++ используют, если 1) уже есть существующих код, 2) уже есть существующая библиотека, 3) нужно закрыть часть кода от взлома, 4) есть жесткие требования по производительности и т.п. и т.д.

Comment: тоесть исходный код программы написанный, например, в Borland C++ Builder можно собрать и отладить по вышеуказанному методу? интересует именно возможность отображения и работы визуальных компонентов (типа StrinGrid и т.п.)

Comment: А каким тут боком билдер? Если его рассматривать как компилятор - да, скорее код перенесется, чем нет. Но если программа использует всяческие TWindow и пр. - про перенос можно забыть 100%.